# Segmentation Fault - ARM Assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

I am trying to load the data pointed to by a `ARM` register `(R0)` to another register `(R1)`

So, I am using `LDR R1,[R0]`. 
But `R0` is an immediate value like
`LDR R0,=0x0804c000`

I get a segmentation fault.

Registers info

```
(gdb) info registers
r0             0x804c000        134529024
r1             0x1      1
r2             0x804c044        134529092
r3             0x1      1
r4             0x804c088        134529160
r5             0x0      0
r6             0x804c0cc        134529228
r7             0xbe9746c4       3197585092
r8             0x804c110        134529296
r9             0x8fb9   36793
r10            0x804c154        134529364
r11            0x0      0
r12            0x0      0
sp             0xbe9746c4       0xbe9746c4
lr             0x8939   35129
pc             0x89f0   0x89f0 <test46+48>
cpsr           0x60000030       1610612784
```

`Disassembler:`

```
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function test46:
   0x000089c0 <+0>:     push    {r7}
   0x000089c2 <+2>:     add     r7, sp, #0
   0x000089c4 <+4>:     ldr     r0, [pc, #60]   ; (0x8a04)
   0x000089c6 <+6>:     ldr     r2, [pc, #64]   ; (0x8a08)
   0x000089c8 <+8>:     ldr     r4, [pc, #64]   ; (0x8a0c)
   0x000089ca <+10>:    ldr     r6, [pc, #68]   ; (0x8a10)
   0x000089cc <+12>:    ldr.w   r8, [pc, #68]   ; 0x8a14
   0x000089d0 <+16>:    ldr.w   r10, [pc, #68]  ; 0x8a18
   0x000089d4 <+20>:    nop
   0x000089d6 <+22>:    nop
   0x000089d8 <+24>:    nop
   0x000089da <+26>:    nop
   0x000089dc <+28>:    nop
   0x000089de <+30>:    nop
   0x000089e0 <+32>:    nop
   0x000089e2 <+34>:    nop
   0x000089e4 <+36>:    nop
   0x000089e6 <+38>:    nop
   0x000089e8 <+40>:    nop
   0x000089ea <+42>:    nop
   0x000089ec <+44>:    nop
   0x000089ee <+46>:    nop
=> 0x000089f0 <+48>:    ldr     r1, [r0, #0]
   0x000089f2 <+50>:    ldr     r3, [r2, #0]
   0x000089f4 <+52>:    ldr     r5, [r4, #0]
   0x000089f6 <+54>:    ldr     r7, [r6, #0]
   0x000089f8 <+56>:    ldr.w   r9, [r8]
   0x000089fc <+60>:    ldr.w   r11, [r10]
   0x00008a00 <+64>:    b.n     0x89f0 <test46+48>
End of assembler dump.
```

Can't LDR instruction be used like that?  I am able to move the data from R0 to R1 without any issue using the following command`MOV R1, R0`

Here are my `compilation flags:`

```
gcc -std=c99 -mthumb -march=armv7 -mthumb-interwork -static -ffunction-sections
```

Comment: I didn't think you could directly access the cache and read it.  What processor are you using?  Can you point me to a datasheet?

Comment: `http://www.arndaleboard.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page`

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Ie, what is the overall purpose or goal?  Are you just playing with assembler or are you actually trying to do something?  If so, can you describe that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by one of your comments in another response, I think your view of how the cache works is wrong.  I don't believe the memory backing the cache is directly accessible, and looking at the datasheet, and I'd say that I'm correct.  The RAM used for caching is usually extremely fast, and it works best if you can avoid the typical address cycles involved when trying to access main memory.  Also, the kernel would not allow direct access to the contents of the L1 because it could cause a lot of trouble for the system, even if you could just read it and not write it--think about another user space process who could examine the content and potentially pull back passwords or other sensitive data from it.  Typically, you do things affecting the cache through the system coprocessor, which you would need to read up on in the [ARM Architecture Manual for the Cortex-A15](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html).

Even if you could directly access it, you're forgetting that there's an MMU and Linux involved.  Linux sets up a virtual memory space that looks considerably different that the physical space of your processor.  In this case, `0x0804c000` is unmapped, so you get a segmentation fault.

I suspect the issue is just a coding error.  FWIW, the snippet you presented looks correct, except that you're accessing an invalid memory location.

Comment: Who said anything about Linux being involved? Why can't he have direct access to memory-mapped cache registers? Who says he's using an A15, and even if he is, who said what flavour?

Comment: Oh, wait, I see the arndaleboard reference now.

Comment: Yes, assuming that the code is running in a privileged mode (kernel or module) then the physical address needs to be mapped to an uncached virtual address before accessing it.

Comment: It doesn't matter about the **Cache**; this answer doesn't make complete sense.  If the memory is not accessible, how does the cache get populated with that value?  The **cache** is a non-sequitur.  It would only matter if you could directly populate (and lock) the **cache**.  Otherwise a cache is, as it should be, a copy of  physical/virtual memory.  If the physical memory is not accessible, then lacking any cache manipulation primitives, it will not be in the cache either.  For 99% of code, Linux doesn't care about the **cache**.

Comment: @artlessnoise Read the OP's comment in ams's response.  Then it'll make a little more sense.

Comment: I have.  The answer still has false information.  He is accessing memory that is not mapped.  End of story.  The cache has nothing to do with it unless you are playing tricks (which he is not).  A cache is transparent, not some temporary buffer like a register bank.  Why are you talking about Linux giving **L1** access?

Comment: Then read it again.  The OP thought you had direct access to L1 and could read off a cache line.  I'm saying that you don't, and even if you could the idea is broken.

Comment: I don't need to read his comments.  Your text didn't make sense to me until your last comment.  You do have *direct access* to the **L1** as in by the normal mechanisms of reading and writing memory; it is built-in to the CPU.  By *direct access* you mean writing directly to the cache?  These are much better links [ARM Cache lockdown procedure](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0329l/Beieiiab.html) and [Lockdown info](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0201d/I33878.html).  There is no way to write directly to the cache.

Comment: Yes, I meant direct access to the RAM backing the cache.

Answer (score 1):

That instruction, `LDR R1, [R0]`, takes an *address* from `R0`, and loads a 32-bit integer, from that address, into `R1`.

If the address in `R0` is not a valid address then you get a segmentation fault. You should set a breakpoint on that instruction and look what's in `R0` at that point.

```
(gdb) break *0x000089f0
(gdb) run
<program hits breakpoint>
(gdb) info registers
<read value from R0>
```

You can then try to load from that address with the debugger to see if it works there:

```
(gdb) x/x $r0
```

If the debugger can read the address then the problem is not what you thought it was; form another hypothesis and test that.

Comment: The value of `R0` is `0x0804c000`

Comment: Well, is that a valid address?

Comment: It is pointing to a cache line. So, yes, it is a valid address.

Comment: `(gdb) x/x $r0`
`0x804c000:      Cannot access memory at address 0x804c000`

Comment: It's a device register? How wide is the register? You might need to use a byte load?

Comment: The L1 cache is 64KB in size; I am missing something - but I dont know what.

Comment: `int test46_array[64*1024]  __attribute__ ((aligned (8192)));`

Comment: @pistal you don't point to a cache line.  You point to an address, and that address may reside within a cache line, but the address may still be invalid.  How are you getting that address?  Are you passing in the address of `test46_array`?

Comment: Yes, I am passing the address of test46_array

Comment: In GDB, can you show the result of `display &test46_array` just before executing the line that segfaults?  Or better yet, maybe the code behind test46 and what's calling it?  It smells like you're either passing in the address wrong, or you've declared `test46_array` to be `extern` and no memory has been allocated for it.